# Count the number of occurrences

Tags: oracle, count, grouping

How can I fulfill the conditions? I need to count the number of records satisfying the conditions

[image]

```
(A || B) && С
(A || B) && !С
(A || B) || С
```

For example first condition

**(A || B) && С**

- num = 1 - Fits the condition. Present in CAT=A, CAT=B and CAT=C
- num = 2 - Fits the condition. Present in CAT=A and CAT=C
- num = 3 - Not suitable by condition. Present only in CAT=C
  (expression (A || B) && С is false)

So result table for expressions looks

```
COLUMN_EXP              COUNT
 (A || B) && С          2
 (A || B) && !С         0
 (A || B) || С          3
```

Comment: did you try a SQL statement?

Comment: What do you have in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Query**:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;

SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN ( A > 0 OR B > 0 ) AND C > 0 THEN 1 END ) AS "(A||B)&&C",
         COUNT( CASE WHEN ( A > 0 OR B > 0 ) AND C = 0 THEN 1 END ) AS "(A||B)&&!C",
         COUNT( CASE WHEN ( A > 0 OR B > 0 ) OR  C > 0 THEN 1 END ) AS "(A||B)||C"
  FROM   your_table
  PIVOT ( COUNT(*) FOR cat IN ( 'A' AS A, 'B' AS B, 'C' AS C ) )
)
UNPIVOT(
  "COUNT" FOR COLUMN_EXP IN ( "(A||B)&&C", "(A||B)&&!C", "(A||B)||C" )
);
```

**Output**:

```
COLUMN_EXP COUNT
---------- -----
(A||B)&&C      2
(A||B)&&!C     0
(A||B)||C      3
```

Comment: I was just about to make a mention to the PIVOT function. A wonderful utility for something like this

Comment: Thank you for anwser. Can I do this with breakdowns for periods? select .... from table GROUP BY  (TO_CHAR (operation_time, 'YYYY-MM') ???

Comment: Thank you for the direction of the solution.